# Unstable build with Maven+Nexus+Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a build environment with Maven3.0.4, Nexus 2.2 and Jenkins 1.508. To support an active and dynamic development environment, all artifacts in my solution use snapshot version and maven tries to get latest snapshot on every build.

The build is not that smooth as expected. Main problem is sometimes build fails due to unresolvable dependencies, and the solution is just re-run the job.

I am suspicious that it is caused by bottleneck in Nexus server in peak load, which causes Maven unable to retrieving pom files during build. But I have no idea about how to diagnose and fix the issue. Anyone has a good idea?

This question has been answered. Please refer to [Does Maven build "thread safe" for snapshot projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584226/does-maven-build-thread-safe-for-snapshot-projects/16586186?noredirect=1#16586186).

B.R.

Comment: Check the build logs to find the exact issue and also post it here so that we can pin point the problem. In Jenkins you can check the logs on the Console Output of the job which fails.

Comment: How are you forcing the retrieval of the latest snapshots? Are you running e.g. mvn clean install -U ? Most likely you different snapshots are getting out of sync. Nexus is probably not the problem.

Comment: Hi Manfred, yes I use -U for each execution. Is there any issue for such usage? I do not understand why different snapshots are getting out of sync, but the error log really indicates such possibility, for example unresovable dependency which does exist, and class not found which does exist as well. Any ideas to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584226/does-maven-build-thread-safe-for-snapshot-projects/16586186?noredirect=1#16586186.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Maven build "thread safe" for snapshot projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584226/does-maven-build-thread-safe-for-snapshot-projects)