# Does Maven build "thread safe" for snapshot projects?

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, snapshot

I have a question regarding parallel maven build. If several maven builds are running in same machine at the same time, and some build results are used by other builds with snapshot version dependency, what will happen? Can maven handle such situation and get correct snapshot version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the explanations here:

[Maven concurrent builds on CI server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565985/maven-concurrent-builds-on-ci-server)

In other words. The behaviour in such cases is not defined, cause the access to the local repository is *not* thread safe.

So i would avoid such things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And the best approach I found till now is modifying settings.xml: <localRepository>c:\m2repo\executor${env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER}</localRepository>. In Jenkins it ensures each executor has own repository so that no intefere from other build jobs.

Comment: In Jenkins it's better to use the configuration which supports to use a local repository (see Advanced of Maven build configuration) without manually modifying the settings.xml. You didn't wrote about Jenkins nor tagged the question accordingly.